# Spring Data Rest/HATEOAS without Spring Boot/MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, spring-rest

Is it possible to use Spring Data Rest/HATEOAS without Spring Boot, Spring MVC on an persistence storage based application. If so how can this be done?

Comment: You question is quite vague. If you can be a little more detailed on what you are trying to accomplish, I could probably give a more detailed answer.

Comment: `to be more specific I am wondering if I need all the spring mvc stuff to provide a rest/hateoas interface htpp endpoints-based api for spring-data server app that would enable easy access for nosql storage.

Comment: Spring-data doesn't handle endpoints, SpringMVC does. What do you plan to use as your web application if not Spring? Whatever web application you choose shouldn't hurt you on the decision to use Hateoas (Hateoas does not use spring-data, but spring-data will use Hateoas). However trying to use spring-data with another web application sounds problematic.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was pretty much all about. I have accepted the ansewer altho this comment is more thatn that one accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. This has been around even before Spring Boot.

The important thing is to ensure the API jars are on your classpath. Get the latest release of Hateoas [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.19.0.RELEASE) and latest release of Spring Data JPA [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.2.RELEASE) and add to the classpath. Just pick from the setup you are using (e.g., Maven, Gradle).

Comment: have you tried it? I am asking because I am trying to get this working for integration tests that are not a Spring Boot project and I am having, precisely, Initialization problems and I suspect that is because something Boot does under the hood because my Traverson code is exactly as in the examples in Spring doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.2.2/reference/html/#client.